# What open course lecture(s) should I attend?

Tags: computer-science

I am a sophomore CS student and I want to spent my summer with e-learning. There are a lot of open course lectures around but I don't know where to start or how to proceed.

**Edit:** Thanks for advices but my real problem is i cant choose which particular lecture should i attend.I mean there are a lot and some are about AI some others about programming languages some others are about network or computer science like discrite mathematics etc...

Comment: Listing some options would be a good idea.

Comment: @Welbog From the way it sounds, he's open to anything out there.

Comment: @Thomas Owens: Well he needs some English, if his question's style is any indication of his ability to write.

Comment: This should be Community Wiki

Answer (score 1):

[MIT Video Gateway](http://watch.mit.edu/)

Also check

[School of Computer Sciences E-Learning](http://e-learning.cs.usm.my/)

in which you can get a wide range of subjects

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend http://www.w3schools.com

This site provides excellent and easily digestible short courses about web based technologies from html/css/javascript to xml.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Some AI lectures:

http://tokyolectures.org/lectures

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

I'd definitely recommend watching the MIT series "[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/)" by Hal Abelson and Gerald Sussman.

There is a link on that page through to a free on-line copy of the matching text book as well.

Hmmm. Now I've finished my revisit to K&R C I might go back though these lectures myself. (-:

HTH

cheers,